# Search Control is not seen on the search results page

Tags: master-page

In my custom master page I added a search control

```
<div id="search-ctrl" class="s4-notdlg">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" Version="4"/>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
```

which I see it on all the pages except the search center results page. On the search results page, the control shows up above the search results and not where I added it in the master page.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the Search Results page doesn't render the page layouts properly unless Minimal.master is the Search Centre's master Page. Try creating a custom master page based off the minimal.master master page.

Answer (score 0):

Search center is a seperate subsite. Verify the masterpage for the Search Center sub site, it must be a different one.